# Out of memory exception on server, but most troubling; events not being called unless I debug

Tags: c#, sockets

I have this very weird error.  Basically, as soon as I add the line of code Connections.Add(handler); my program goes haywire.  I'm also getting the error:

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.CreateCopy()    at
>   System.Net.ContextAwareResult.CaptureOrComplete(ExecutionContext&
>   cachedContext, Boolean returnContext)

What happens is, when I add this code, connections are still being accepted, but nothing is being logged on my log richtextbox control.  This is very weird, and I have no idea whats going on.  However, removing that Connections.Add(handler) line in my accept event solves all problems.  But I need to keep track of sockets somehow so I can implement pinging to keep them alive

Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace SpybotServer
{  
    public partial class Server : Form
    {  

        public void log(String text)
        {
            logs.InvokeEx(a => a.Text += (text +Environment.NewLine));
        }

        public Server()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void Server_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            Thread serverThread = new Thread(delegate()
                {
                    Listener.StartListening(9001);
                });
            serverThread.Start();
            heartbeat.Start();
        }

        private void Server_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Listener.looping = false;
        }

        private void heartbeat_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Listener.heartbeat();
        }

    }

    public class StateObject
    {
        public Socket workSocket = null;
        public const int BufferSize = 1024;
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public class Listener
    {       
        public static Boolean looping = true;
        private static List<Socket> Connections = new List<Socket>();

        public static void heartbeat()
        {
            Program.MainForm.log("Sending ping...");             
        }

        public static void StartListening(int port)
        {
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9001);
            Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            Program.MainForm.log("Listening on port " + port);

            try
            {
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                listener.Listen(100);

                while (looping)
                {
                    listener.BeginAccept(
                        new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                        listener);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Program.MainForm.log(e.ToString());
            }
        }

        public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.workSocket = handler;
            IPEndPoint ip = handler.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;                    

            Program.MainForm.log("Accepted connection from " + ip.Address);
            //Connections.Add(handler);

            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }

        public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            String content = String.Empty;
            StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.workSocket;

            try
            {
                int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                        state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                    content = state.sb.ToString();                    

                    /*if (content.IndexOf("!@<EOF_END>@!") > -1)
                    {
                        Program.MainForm.log(content);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                    }*/
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Program.MainForm.log(e.ToString());
            }
        }


        private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
        {
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

            handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            try
            {                
                int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
                if (bytesSent <= 0)
                {
                    Program.MainForm.log("Socket has been closed.");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Program.MainForm.log(e.ToString());
                handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                handler.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

InvokeEx:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace SpybotServer
{
    static class ISynchronizeInvokeExtensions
    {
        public static void InvokeEx<T>(this T @this, Action<T> action) where T : ISynchronizeInvoke
        {
            if (@this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                @this.Invoke(action, new object[] { @this });
            }
            else
            {
                action(@this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this callback:

```
public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
```

is inside this loop:

```
while (looping)
{
    listener.BeginAccept(
        new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
        listener);
}
```

I'm more than 90% certain that you are adding the same `Socket` to the `Connections` list over and over and just growing the size of the list at an alarming rate. Change the add to this:

```
if (Connections.Contains(handler))
{
    Connections.Add(handler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Michael is on the right track, but not with the right solution.

```
listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener);
```

Is (unlike `Accept`) not going to block and weird things are going to happen if you call it this way.  Instead take your `BeginAccept` out of a loop and call it again from `AcceptCallback` so that you can accept a new connection *after* you have accepted a first.